# how do i fix the ''Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component' error in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, router

i am trying to use the usehistory hook In react but i keep getting this error
×
Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

```
   import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../context/firebase';
import { Form } from '../components';
import { HeaderContainer } from '../containers/Header';
import { FooterContainer } from '../containers/Footer';
import * as ROUTES from '../constant/routes';

export default function SignIn() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const isInvalid = password === '' || emailAddress === '';

  const handleSignin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password)
      .then(() => {
        history.push(ROUTES.BROWSE);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setEmailAddress('');
        setPassword('');
        setError(error.message);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Does this help at all? https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

Comment: Doesn't look like the issue is in the code you're showing us.